# R - Highcharter, How to avoid increasing the indentation of the y axis label?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Is there a way to **avoid the increasing indention of the y axis label** with each successive graph?

```
library(xts)
library(highcharter)

dates = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by="day")
x1 = xts(c(2,3,1,5), dates)
x2 = xts(c(1,1.5,2,1), dates)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
   hc_yAxis_multiples(
     list(top = "0%", height = "60%", title = list(text = "Var1")),
     list(top = "60%", height = "40%", title = list(text = "Var2"))) %>%
   hc_add_series(x1, yAxis=0, compare="percent", color="blue") %>%
   hc_add_series(x2, yAxis=1, color="black")
```

The graph created is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by manually setting [`offset`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.offset) of the second y-axis. From the API reference:

> offset: number
>
> The distance in pixels from the plot area to the axis line. A positive
>   offset moves the axis with it's line, labels and ticks away from the
>   plot area. **This is typically used when two or more axes are
>   displayed on the same side of the plot. With multiple axes the offset
>   is dynamically adjusted to avoid collision, this can be overridden by
>   setting offset explicitly.**
>
> Defaults to 0.

```r
highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(top = "0%", height = "60%", title = list(text = "Var1")),
    list(top = "60%", height = "40%", offset = 0, title = list(text = "Var2"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(x1, yAxis=0, compare="percent", color="blue") %>%
  hc_add_series(x2, yAxis=1, color="black")
```

[image]